# Laravel execute SQL Server stored procedure with output

Tags: sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I working with Laravel 5.3 and MSSQL. I have problem when executing a stored procedure with output.

My stored procedure:

```
create proc spud_test_laravel
(
    @input nvarchar(50),
    @output nvarchar(50) output
)
as
begin
   set @output = @input
end
```

Please help my to execute this stored procedure and return the output. I tried many ways but without success.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the stored procedure using laravel DB builder like

```
$result = DB::select('spud_test_laravel(1)');
```

Comment: i want to execute the store procedure men. not to create this. anw thanks men

Comment: I tried with this but return error

    ===>>> Procedure or function 'spud_test_laravel' expects parameter '@output', which was not supplied. (SQL: spud_test_laravel 1)

my code in laravel ==> $result = DB::select('spud_test_laravel 1');
    echo $result;